# How to replay a Puppeteer HTTPRequest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Using Puppeteer, I am able to intercept HTTPResponses and their HTTPRequests:

```js
page.on("response", async response => {
    let request = response.request(); // Getting the response request
    let responseHeaders = response.headers(); // Check response headers
    response.buffer().then(buffer => {
         // Play with response content
     });
})
```

Depending on the response content, I need to send the request again like a fresh one and get its response buffer. Instantiating an identical and new request is a valid option.

I know I could use node-fetch as a last resort, but Puppeteer seems to have everything embedded to do it without adding packages.

Do you know how to achieve this?

- [Puppeteer HTTPRequest doc](https://devdocs.io/puppeteer-httprequest/)
- [Puppeteer HTTPRequest class](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/src/common/HTTPRequest.ts)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `page.evaluate` to send a post request using fetch API

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
    return fetch('url', {method: 'POST', body: 'test' }).then(res => res.json())
})
```

So then you can make a request after the `requestfinished` event fired.

```
page.setRequestInterception(true)
page.on('requestfinished', async (request: Request) => {
    let response = request.response()                   // Getting the response request
    let responseHeaders = response.headers()            // Check response headers
    let responseBuffer = await response.buffer()        // Get the buffer required
    let responseJSON = await response.json()            // Get parsed JSON body
    await page.evaluate(([headers, buffer, json]) => {  // Replay request with buffer received
        let someData1 = buffer.toString()               // Change buffer to string type
        let someData2 = headers['Content-Type']         // or maybe use some headers data
        let someData3 = json.properties.value           // or use response data object properties
                                                        // This fetch API below will do the rest
        return fetch('url', { method: 'POST', body: 'test' }).then(res => res.json())
    }, [responseHeaders, responseBuffer, responseJSON])
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however the bounty is more about using Puppeteer's HTTPRequest class

Comment: There is a method `gotoExtended` which has the same goal as yours. Developed by Apify: https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/puppeteer#puppeteergotoextended
Source:
https://github.com/apify/apify-js/blob/1d467ad3a4a4f3a87028fa023f25f51c060ddb95/src/puppeteer_utils.js#L343